# i m looking for a guide to use mysql commands in strawberry perl

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

my aim is to create a database and use a regular commands in strawberry perl...

Many are saying "StrawberryPerl comes bundled with drivers for MySQL"
how to setup the necessary development environment...
how to start? and where to start???

Comment: [DBD::mysql](http://p3rl.org/DBD::mysql)

Comment: A driver for MySQL is not a database server. It's just the thing in between Perl and the DB server that lets you talk to the DB. You will need an actual MySQL server. If you don't have that and feel it is too complicated, maybe take a look at sqlite.

Comment: What are "regular commands"?

Answer (score 2):

```
use DBI qw( );

my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {
   AutoCommit => 1,
   PrintWarn  => 1,
   PrintError => 0,
   RaiseError => 1,
});
```

If the database server is on another machine, add `";host=$hostname"` to the DSN.

If the database server is on a port other than the default, add `";port=$port"` to the DSN.

Refer to [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI)'s documentation for how to issue queries.

Comment: @Sahi: what did ikegami say about <code>";host=$hostname"</code?
Do you know how to create a variable in Perl?
If you are new to Perl, check out the resources at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org).

Comment: Please be accurate when quoting error messages. What DSN did you use, and what's the actual error message you received?